# How do I work with integers that result in bigger than 10 with MIPS?

Tags: mips, fibonacci

I am trying to make a Fibonacci sequence with MIPS and this is the code I have so far.

```
main:
    li $t1, 0
    li $t2, 1
    
    add $t3, $t1, $t2
    
    loop:
        add $t3, $t1, $t2
        la $t1, ($t3)
        
        add $t3, $t1, $t2
        la $t2, ($t3)
        j loop
```

It works fine until it gets to 8, it should then be adding 5 to make 13 but instead the register shows 0x0000000d, then it completely messes up the sequence, somehow a 15 comes up then 22 then 37.
I'm guessing it has something to do with the carry but how would I actually deal with this so that it carries on with the sequence properly?

Thank you

Comment: d in hex is 13.  Your debugger is showing you hex, but 13 decimal is the same numeric value as d hex.  Some debuggers have an option to display in decimal: MARS, for example, has within the Settings menu, check box "Values displayed in hexadecimal" -- uncheck it for decimal values instead.

Comment: Don't use `la` to copy values between registers: use `move` instead.

Comment: Thanks to both of you it works now. But it started working perfectly as soon as I unchecked show in hex, I want to understand why it was giving me 15 then 22 in the sequence instead of 13 then 21, surely it should be giving me the same values but in hex before? A bit confused on that part. Thanks

Comment: It was always working.  The display option just changed the debugger's display radix, but it did not otherwise change the simulator's or program's behavior.